# Setting an <li class="active"> using MasterPage

Tags: asp.net, master-pages

Code below I have located under my MasterPage. Once one of the tabs get clicked for example "Contact Us" I would like to set the *li class* to active. I cannot figure out how to do this. Any help would be great.

```
<div id="navcontainer">
    <div class="section-wrapper">
        <ul class="links">      
            <li class="">                
                <a href="">Our Company</a>
            </li>       
            <li class="">               
                    <a href="Contact%20Us/Default.aspx">Contact Us</a>
            </li>       
            <li class="">                
                    <a href="">Tab 3</a>
            </li>       
            <li class="">                
                    <a href="">Tab 4</a>
            </li>   
            <li class="">                
                    <a href="">Tab 5</a>
            </li>               
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you mean setting class active like this class="active" from the child page

Comment: hey Thank for reply. Yes that is what I would like to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        HtmlGenericControl tabContact = Master.FindControl("liContact") as HtmlGenericControl;
        tabContact.Attributes.Add("class", "active");
        Master.FindControl("liContact").Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<span></span>"));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with jQuery, like so:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 

<script>
$("li").click(function(){
    alert("this is the message");
    if ($("li").hasClass('active')) {
        $("li").removeClass('active');
    }
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
</script>
```

[Here is an example of your code.](http://jsfiddle.net/YjwqN/)

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply I get the following error: Microsoft JScript runtime error: '$' is undefined

Comment: The reason you have that error is that you need to call your jQuery before the script. I updated my answer to show you the full js section. Add the line above and you will be good to go.

Comment: Hey Thanks again I appreciate it. Now I got no error and got onto another page but the css is not getting triggered. hmmm

Comment: Good. I added an alert in my answer and it works perfectly. Here is an example link: http://jsfiddle.net/YjwqN/1/ So you want the CSS to change on the page that it link to? Is this a separate page or is it loaded via ajax?

Comment: Hey Thanks again for the reply. I have the links set up within my master page and when you click on the link it will take me to another page and than I would like css to change once transferred onto a new page. Thew new page for example "Contact Us" uses the Master Page.

Comment: I am thinking the example you gave me only works on the "click" event and it does not keep its css once the page is redirected.

Answer (score 1):

Have a public property on the page with default value and use this property to set CSS in your page.

Default.aspx.cs

```
public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public string ActiveTab = "contact";

    public void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

Default.aspx

```
<ul class="links">      
    <li class="">                
        <a href="">Our Company</a>
    </li>       
    <li class="<% if (ActiveTab=="contact") { %>active<% } %>">
            <a href="Contact%20Us/Default.aspx">Contact Us</a>
    </li>       
    <li class="">                
            <a href="">Tab 3</a>
    </li>       
    <li class="">                
            <a href="">Tab 4</a>
    </li>   
    <li class="">                
            <a href="">Tab 5</a>
    </li>               
</ul>
```

Once css of li is set, use CSS to visually represent it as active.